# Display dates in month wise

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've select some dates from the database and display these dates in month wise.. Am using the following code

```
$work_res = mysql_query("(SELECT DISTINCT date FROM `work_details` WHERE  employee_id='" . $emp_id . "' and date between  '" . $qsdate . "' and '" . $qedate . "') UNION (SELECT holy_date from holiday where holy_date between  '" . $qsdate . "' and '" . $qedate . "')");


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($work_res)) {
 echo date("F", $test_date).'<br>';
        while ((date("Y-m-d", $test_date) < $row['date']) && ($flag = 0)) {

            if (!(date('N', strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $test_date))) >= 6)) {

                echo "<tr ><td align=center class=fontclass style=color:FF0000>" . date("Y-m-d F", $test_date) . "</td></tr>";
            }
            $test_date = $test_date + ($day_incrementer * 60 * 60 * 24);
        }
        $flag = 1;


        while ((date("Y-m-d", $test_date) != $row['date'])) {

            if (!(date('N', strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $test_date))) >= 6)) {
                echo "<tr><td align=center class=fontclass style=color:FF0000>" . date("Y-m-d F", $test_date) . "</td></tr>";
            }
            $test_date = $test_date + ($day_incrementer * 60 * 60 * 24);
        }
        $test_date = $test_date + ($day_incrementer * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }


    while (date("Y-m-d", $test_date) <= date("Y-m-d", $end_date)) {
        if (!(date('N', strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $test_date))) >= 6)) {
            echo "<tr><td align=center class=fontclass style=color:FF0000>" . date("Y-m-d F", $test_date) . "</td></tr>";
        }
        $test_date = $test_date + ($day_incrementer * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }


    return;
}
```

Got the result like

```
2012-01-16 January
2012-01-26 January
2012-01-27 January
2012-02-02 February
2012-03-21 March
2012-03-22 March
```

I want to display these dates like

```
 January (3)
    2012-01-16
    2012-01-26
    2012-01-27
February (1)
    2012-02-02 
March(2)
    2012-03-21 
    2012-03-22
```

Is this possible? Please help

Comment: Not able to understand what you are doing in the code by checking with test_date, start_date and end_date ? To display like that why you need all the above stuff? it can be done through query.

Comment: $qsdate = date("Y") . "-01-01";
    $qedate = date("Y-m-d");

    $start_date = strtotime($qsdate);
    $end_date = strtotime($$qedate);

    $test_date = $start_date;
    $day_incrementer = 1;
    $count_leaves = 0;
    $flag = 0;

Comment: I can give the code by removing all the above conditions and the format your requested.Those dates you are displaying are from database right?

Comment: i've calculate leaves taken by an employee.table contains all the working days details and holidays of each year.calculate leave on the basis of these details and also exclude saturdays and sundays...this is working properly..mistake is in the format of display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that will work but needs to be tested. You need to insert your logic in the  ***dateIsValid()*** function.

```
<?php

$work_res = mysql_query("(SELECT DISTINCT date FROM `work_details` WHERE  employee_id='" . $emp_id . "' and date between  '" . $qsdate . "' and '" . $qedate . "') UNION (SELECT holy_date from holiday where holy_date between  '" . $qsdate . "' and '" . $qedate . "')");


 //Group all dates into their Months
 while($result =  @mysql_fetch_array($work_res))
  {
    $date = $result['date'];
    $month = date("F",$date );

    //Your complex logic in between...
    if(dateIsValid())
       $output[$month][] = date("Y-m-d", $date);
  }

 //Display as required
 foreach($output as $month => $dates)
  {
    echo $month." (".count($dates).")"; //Echo the month heading
    foreach($dates as $date) echo $date; //Echo the date
  }
```

**Notes :**

1. This grouping is possible in SQL and should most probably done
   over there.
2. Move all your logic to a separate function
3. For db access use PHP's [PDO API](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) or an ORM like redBean
4. Write comments in your code Comments should explain what logic has been implemented.
5. Use better variable names.
6. Use DateTime instead of date() (See comment below).

Comment: I just need to point out that this code would break with dates in 2037 or later. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=7103. This can be fixed using `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

You want an array where the key is the full month name. You'll want to do something like this...

---

### Here is a sample script: http://codepad.org/pJOpDr17

```
$dateArray=array();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($work_res)){
    $d = new DateTime($row['date']);
    $monthName = $d->format('F');
    //$monthName = $d->format('F_Y'); (If you want month_year)
    $dateArray[$monthName][] = $row['date'];
}
```

---

### SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
array(3) {
  ["January"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2012-01-16"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2012-01-26"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "2012-01-27"
  }
  ["February"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2012-02-02"
  }
  ["March"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2012-03-21"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2012-03-22"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get what you are looking for

Use DateTime like Dutchie432 suggested

```
result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($work_res))
{
  $tmp_time = strtotime(row['date']);
  $tmp_month = date('F',$tmp_time);
  $tmp_date = date('Y-m-d', $tmp_time);
  if(!is_array($result[$tmp_month]))
  {
    $result[$tmp_month] = array();
  }
  array_push(result[$tmp_month], $tmp_date);
}

# this will print something similar to your req
foreach($result as $month => $dates)
{
  echo $month . " (" . $result[$month].length . ")";
  foreach($dates as $date)
  {
    echo $date;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just need to point out that this code would break with dates in 2037 or later. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=7103. This can be fixed using `DateTime`

Comment: Yeah that's true but I doubt it will survive that long.

Comment: A) how could you possibly know that? B) What if the OP is calculating future dates?

Comment: if(!array_key_exists($tmp_month, $result)) This would be a better option instead of is_array()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the dates as and when add the dates to an array like

wherever you are using echo $test_date apend to an array say

```
$leavesTakes[]=$date("Y-m-d F", $test_date)
```

and now use the loop to display dates

```
for($i=0;$i<count($leavesTakes);$i++)
{
  $cnt=0;
  for($j=$i;$j<count($leavestaken);$j++)
  {
    if($leavesTaken[$i]!=$leavesTaken[$j])
        break;

     $cnt++;
  }

  //print month name
  echo '<tr><td> month name (' + $cnt + ')'; //print month name

  for(;$i<$j;$i++)        
    echo '<br/>$date("Y-m-d F", $leavesTaken[$i]);

   echo '</td></tr>';

}
```

I dont know the format to print the month name from the date. So please ignore print month name and replace with the actual php function to print month name